# Java String to CharArray, hidden manner

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I got another nooby question to Java gurus

Basically what I want is:

1. Take word;
2. Transform it to arrayOfChar;
3. Hide it to following manner: `_ _ _ _`;

I could get to to second step, however when I try to hide word in underscores it shows as `____` rather than `_ _ _ _`.

Code for it:

```
//Randomly picks word from Array which played 
public String pickWord(){
    String guessWord = (wordsList[new Random().nextInt(wordsList.length)]);
    return guessWord;
}

//Hides picked word
public char[] setWord(){
    word = pickWord().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength (word); i++) {
        word[i] = '_';
    }
    return word;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to allow for the spaces in your new char array:

```
    String testWord = "test";
    char[] word = new char[testWord.length() * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i+=2) {
        word[i] = '_';
        word[i + 1] = ' ';
    }
```

Comment: It does exactly the same, just shorter version. Wondering if I can maybe just insert another loop to make spaces between them...

Comment: no need to insert another loop. Just override that '_' with '  ' in the same loop when you have i%2!=0. see my answer

Comment: Updated, dont forget to add the spaces

Answer (score 0):

Add extra condition in for-loop

```
if(i%2 == 0)
word[i]='_'; 
else
word[i]=' ';
```

or simply override the word[i] only when i%2 =0. just one if block after you have

```
  word[i]='_';
  if(i%2 != 0)
  word[i]=' ';
```

Comment: It did give me _ _, but my word is 4 letter word so I assume it transforms two letter to underscores and two to spaces

Comment: Did not get you. You wanted to retain same number of chars but introduce an extra space between them? If thats the case you can use other sols posted here otherwise you can just override alternate '_' with space

Answer (score 0):

When you store '*' in  word variable and print it it shows "*__*" because it shows consecutive '*' . You can do it in various ways- like you can put a space every character of word or padding a space in word variable

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength (word); i++) {
        word[2*i] = '_';
        word[2*i+1] = ' ';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word = pickWord().toCharArray();
spacedWord = new char[word.length*2-1];
for (int i = 0; i < 2*word.length; i+=2) {
    spacedWord[i] = '_';
    spacedWord[i+1] = ' ';
}
return spacedWord;
```